Type is not visible: ConnectApi Deploy error
Recently when I try to deploy code with VS code, I'm getting following error:
Type is not visible: ConnectApi.OmnichannelInventoryService

Strange thing is that this didn't happened before. Also colleague does not have this error when trying to deploy same code to his Sandbox.
Only thing that I was able to find was this article: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4T9wSAF
But I checked and license is there. So I don't know what else to try.
Did anyone experienced similar error and maybe know how to solve it?

Make sure you're using the latest version of the API

Make sure that the API version of your Apex class or trigger is compatible with the ConnectApi.OmnichannelInventoryService class. This class is available in API version 51.0 and later.
If your organization uses a namespace prefix, ensure that you are referencing the class correctly with the namespace prefix.

@TusharJadav Version is 58.0
